# Convert an unstructured list of dictionary to structured list of dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, scripting, dataformat

I have below content as output.

```
    ['{end_date=2021-09-16 06:00:00, number=CHG1757, requested_by=Tom, cmdb_ci=Checkout, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}',
 '{end_date=2021-09-16 09:00:00, number=CHG17486, requested_by=Bobby, cmdb_ci=Reservation, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}',
 '{end_date=2021-09-16 12:00:00, number=CHG17441, requested_by=Ryan, cmdb_ci=Payment, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}']
```

Need to convert above output to structured list of dictionaries(see below) using python script.

```
 [{'end_date'='2021-09-16 06:00:00', 'number'='CHG1757', 'requested_by'='Tom', 'cmdb_ci'='Checkout', 'start_date'='2021-09-16 03:00:00'}',
 {'end_date'='2021-09-16 09:00:00', 'number'='CHG17486', 'requested_by'='Bobby', 'cmdb_ci'='Reservation', 'start_date'='2021-09-16 03:00:00'}',
 {'end_date'='2021-09-16 12:00:00', 'number'='CHG17441', 'requested_by'='Ryan', 'cmdb_ci'='Payment', 'start_date'='2021-09-16 03:00:00'}']
```

Answer (score 0):

Praful, how are you doing?

You can try use code below, but only will work if all strings have the same length.

```
stack = ['{end_date=2021-09-16 06:00:00, number=CHG1757, requested_by=Tom, cmdb_ci=Checkout, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}',
         '{end_date=2021-09-16 09:00:00, number=CHG17486, requested_by=Bobby, cmdb_ci=Reservation, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}',
         '{end_date=2021-09-16 12:00:00, number=CHG17441, requested_by=Ryan, cmdb_ci=Payment, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}']

splited = []
for line in stack:
    splited.append(line.split(','))

dict_to_fill = {}
new_list = []
for item in splited:
    dict_to_fill['end_date'] = item[0][10:]
    dict_to_fill['number'] = item[1][8:]
    dict_to_fill['requested_by'] = item[2][14:]
    dict_to_fill['cmdb_ci'] = item[3][9:]
    dict_to_fill['start_date'] = item[4][12:-1]
    new_list.append(dict_to_fill.copy())

print(new_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'end_date': '2021-09-16 06:00:00',
  'number': 'CHG1757',
  'requested_by': 'Tom',
  'cmdb_ci': 'Checkout',
  'start_date': '2021-09-16 03:00:00'},
 {'end_date': '2021-09-16 09:00:00',
  'number': 'CHG17486',
  'requested_by': 'Bobby',
  'cmdb_ci': 'Reservation',
  'start_date': '2021-09-16 03:00:00'},
 {'end_date': '2021-09-16 12:00:00',
  'number': 'CHG17441',
  'requested_by': 'Ryan',
  'cmdb_ci': 'Payment',
  'start_date': '2021-09-16 03:00:00'}]
```

Tell me if worked.

See ya!

Comment: I am doing well, thanks. Your code output repeats the last item of the nested dictionary only. Is there any miss here? Please let me know. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry about that. We need to copy a dictionary if we want to append it. Otherwise python will consider it like reference. You have to put         new_list.append(dict_to_fill.copy())

Comment: Thanks, this works for me!

Comment: Could you help me to rearrange the output based on the key specified in this order(cmdb_ci, number, requested_by,start_date,end_date). [{cmdb_ci': 'Checkout','number': 'CHG1757','requested_by': 'Tom','start_date': '2021-09-16 03:00:00','end_date': '2021-09-16 06:00:00',},...and so on]

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the dynamic code to solve your issue:

```
stack = ['{end_date=2021-09-16 06:00:00, number=CHG1757, requested_by=Tom, cmdb_ci=Checkout, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}',
         '{end_date=2021-09-16 09:00:00, number=CHG17486, requested_by=Bobby, cmdb_ci=Reservation, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}',
         '{end_date=2021-09-16 12:00:00, number=CHG17441, requested_by=Ryan, cmdb_ci=Payment, start_date=2021-09-16 03:00:00}']
         
output = []
for data in stack:
    data = data.replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",")
    format_dict = {}
    for record in data:
        key, value = record.split("=")
        format_dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    output.append(format_dict)

print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks Vimlesh, that works.
Is there any way to rearrange the output based on the key specified in this order(cmdb_ci, number, requested_by,start_date,end_date).

`[{cmdb_ci': 'Checkout','number': 'CHG1757','requested_by': 'Tom','start_date': '2021-09-16 03:00:00','end_date': '2021-09-16 06:00:00',},...and so on]`

Comment: That's not a good approach to do with dict. We can sort  list of dict based on certain key but arranging dict itself for each key not useful.